# Spring boot: Why gives Rest API request an error 403 while Curl works fine?

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

I work on a centos 7 system with spring boot 2.1.4.

My rest-api application has two steps: First it gets a token, then it takes this token to send a document to recipient.

Although the curl tests are successful, I get in step two an 403 in my application.

These curls work successful in the console, document will be created in step 2:

request step 1)

```
curl -s -X POST "https://[URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]/wbOAuth2.token" -u "[usr]:[pwd]" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

answer step 1)

```
{
  "access_token":"WNY0TS3_6oQcn5FIt9tnvUGdVBcXx41sG13inN021Yg="
, "token_type":"bearer"
, "expires_in":"1800"
}
```

request step 2)

```
curl -v -s -X GET "[URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]/pl/rest/loc_dsemrexwritebacktest.fetchemrexresult?access_token=WNY0TS3_6oQcn5FIt9tnvUGdVBcXx41sG13inN021Yg=&PNAME=doc.pdf&PURL=[DOC_URL]"
```

answer step 2)

```
* About to connect() to proxy [IP] port 8888 (#0)
*   Trying [IP]...
* Connected to [IP] ([IP]) port 8888 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to [URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]:443
> CONNECT [URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: [URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established
< Proxy-agent: tinyproxy/1.8.4
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
* Server certificate:
*       subject: CN=[URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]
*       start date: Aug 06 14:30:29 2017 GMT
*       expire date: Nov 02 14:30:29 2020 GMT
*       common name: [URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]
> GET [...] HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: [URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Fri, 09 Aug 2019 20:31:57 GMT
< Server: Oracle-HTTP-Server-12c
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
< X-Frame-Options: sameorigin
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Length: 256
< X-HTTP-Code: 201
< Content-Type: application/xml; model=model-unknown
< Content-Language: en
<
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<codata:resources xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:codata="[...]/xsd/meta/codata/v1" xsi:schemaLocation="[...]/xsd/meta/codata/v1 codata.xsd"/>
* Connection #0 to host [IP] left intact
```

---

The equivalent in my app works in step 1 (Token), but not in step 2 (Creating of the document). This is my code:

```
package rism.controller;

import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Proxy;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.http.client.SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.util.LinkedMultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import rism.model.recipient.RecipientAccessToken;

//TODO: make configurable
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:10021", "http://localhost:11021", "https://[URL_DOC.SENDER]",
        "http://[URL_DOC.SENDER]" })
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/export")
public class ExportController {

    static final private String TOKEN_SERVICE_URL = "[URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]/wbOAuth2.token";
    static final private String TOKEN_SERVICE_USER = "[usr]";
    static final private String TOKEN_SERVICE_SECRET = "[pwd]";

    static final private String EXPORT_SERVICE = "[URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]/pl/rest/loc_dsemrexwritebacktest.fetchemrexresult";

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT)

    public void exportDocument(@RequestParam String transactionId, @RequestParam String mtkNr) {
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        Proxy myProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("[IP]", 8888));
        requestFactory.setProxy(myProxy);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);

        HttpHeaders accessTokenHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        String auth = TOKEN_SERVICE_USER + ":" + TOKEN_SERVICE_SECRET;
        byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.getEncoder().encode(auth.getBytes());
        String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
        accessTokenHeaders.add("Authorization", authHeader);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> accessTokenMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        accessTokenMap.add("grant_type", "client_credentials");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> accessTokenRequest = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(
                accessTokenMap, accessTokenHeaders);

        RecipientAccessToken accessToken = restTemplate.postForObject(TOKEN_SERVICE_URL, accessTokenRequest,
                RecipientAccessToken.class);

        System.out.println("Access token requested: " + accessToken.getAccessToken());

        /* - from here step 2- */

        MultiValueMap<String, String> exportServiceMap = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        exportServiceMap.add("access_token", accessToken.getAccessToken());
        exportServiceMap.add("PURL",
                String.format("https://[URL_DOC.SENDER]/api/document/transaction/%s/pdf/", transactionId));
        exportServiceMap.add("PNAME", transactionId);
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> exportServiceRequest = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>>(
                exportServiceMap, null);
        ResponseEntity<?> recipientServiceResponse = restTemplate.exchange(EXPORT_SERVICE, HttpMethod.GET,
                exportServiceRequest, (Class<?>) null);

        System.out.println("Sent document to Recipient: " + recipientServiceResponse.getStatusCodeValue());

    }
}
```

The nohup log shows this entry:

```
2019-08-09 23:05:04.033 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/api/export?

transactionId=_b5d629955ccade23588a853f379accae050820191214532607308205402172018", parameters={masked}
2019-08-09 23:05:04.034 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to public void controller.ExportController.exportDocument

(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
2019-08-09 23:05:04.057 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP POST [URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]/wbOAuth2.token
2019-08-09 23:05:04.061 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Accept=[application/json, application/*+json]
2019-08-09 23:05:04.062 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{grant_type=[client_credentials]}] with 

org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
2019-08-09 23:05:04.365 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 200 OK
Access token requested: 3SSrRgsReAoLRcCJKDNhyPga6wzU6UYxqJRLf8nYRMs=
2019-08-09 23:05:04.368 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : HTTP GET [URL_DOC.RECIPIENT]/pl/rest/loc_dsemrexwritebacktest.fetchemrexresult
2019-08-09 23:05:04.368 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{access_token=[3SSrRgsReAoLRcCJKDNhyPga6wzU6UYxqJRLf8nYRMs=], PURL=

[URL_DOC.SENDER]/api/document/transaction/_b5d629955ccade23588a853f379accae050820191214532607308205402172018/pdf/], PNAME=[doc.pdf]}] with 

org.springframework.http.converter.support.AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter
2019-08-09 23:05:04.428 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Response 403 FORBIDDEN
2019-08-09 23:05:04.430 DEBUG 4732 --- [io-10010-exec-5] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Failed to complete request: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException

$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
```

There You can see the error: 403 Forbidden. But what is the problem?

Thank You very much for helping.

Comment: You're trying to send the parameters of the GET request as its body. They need to be in the URL.

Comment: @JBNizet Doesn't I do it in the exportServiceMap? Would You explain it a little more detailled?

Comment: No, you're not. Read the javadc: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.lang.String-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object...-. It says: *requestEntity - the entity (headers and/or body) to write to the request*. You don't want to send any body. You want the parameters to be in the URL.

Comment: You are right. It works, since I added the values to the url directly. Thank you very much! :-) I would mark your answer as solution, if You want.

Comment: I faced same issue. my issue was resolved after adding , headers.add(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "HTTPClient/1.0"); and parameter added on url for GET request.